# Does tris(ethylenediamine)iron(III) exhibit optical isomerism?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, coordination-compounds, transition-metals, isomers

I'm studying 12th. In my book they mentioned that $\ce{[Co(en)3]^3+}$ exhibits optical isomerism.

But in that same book, there is a question

> Which of this doesn't exhibit isomerism?

and the answer is $\ce{[Fe(en)3]^3+}.$ Since both complexes have the same structure, then why they are saying $\ce{[Fe(en)3]^3+}$ doesn't show isomerism?

Comment: It would be nice if you could add the citation for your book, including author(s), title, edition, publisher, year, page number(s) and IDs (e.g. ISBN). On Chemistry.SE, ACS citation style is preferred.

Comment: It is my textbook!!

Comment: Good news: you can cite *your* textbooks as well.

Comment: Okay. They gave these options..

Comment: a) [Ni(NH3)4(H2O)2]2+

Comment: b) [Pt(NH3)2Cl2] c)[Co(NH3)5SO4]Cl d)[Fe(en)3]3+     Which should I choose?

Comment: That's not at all what I'm asking. "To cite" means to provide extensive bibliographic information about your source.

Comment: Apparently Vijay refuses to answer Andselisk's question. He refuses to give the author's name of his book,

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer given in your textbook is either incorrect or a misprint. I let you find out the correct answer from given choices.

However, I'd like like to claim that the given answer is wrong because of following facts:

- Tris(ethylenediamine) complexes of transition metals have been studied for more than 100 years and $\ce{M(en)3^3+}$ complexes are been considered chiral (*e.g.*, Ref.1 for studies on $\ce{Co(en)3^3+}$).
- The enanti­omeric nature of these complexes has been verified by X-ray crystallography (*e.g.*, Ref.2 for studies on $\ce{Co(en)3^3+}$).
- The crystal structures of the first-row transition-metal series of tris­­(ethyl­enedi­amine) di­acetate complexes have been recently studied (Ref.3) to show their chiral nature, and following common structure is given for the complexes with $\ce{M^2+}$ central metal:

[image: tris­­(ethyl­enedi­amine) di­acetate complexes]

The abstract states that:

> The crystal structures of the first-row transition-metal series of tris­(ethyl­enedi­amine-$\kappa^2$*N,N′*)metal(II) di­acetate, $\ce{[M(C2H8N2)3](CH3CO2)2}$, with $\ce{M = Mn, Fe, Co, Ni, Cu,}$ and $\ce{Zn}$, are reported. The complexes are all isostructural, crystallizing in a centrosymmetric triclinic cell and possessing an asymmetric unit composed of one $\ce{[M(en)3]^2+}$ cation and two symmetrically independent acetate anions. In the unit cell, the two complex cations are inversion-generated enanti­omers, possessing the energetically favoured Δ(λλλ) and Λ(δδδ) configurations. The complex cations and acetate anions combine through a series of $\ce{N—H⋯O}$ hydrogen bonds to generate a three-dimensional network in the crystals. The other notable feature of the series is a significant Jahn–Teller distortion for the $\mathrm{d^9}$ $\ce{Cu^2+}$ complex.

It is a fact that structures of these same first-row transition-metal series with 3+ oxidation state would give the same octahedral shapes, the cation of which are chiral (*e.g.*, Ref.1 and Ref.2). Examples of few are given below:

[image: Metal 3+ Complexes]

Overall, it is true that the $\ce{[Fe(en)3]^3+}$ cation is chiral.

**References:**

1. A. Werner, "Zur Kenntnis des asymmetrischen Kobaltatoms. V,"  *Berichte der deutschen chemischen Gesellschaft* **1912**, *45(1)*, 121-130 (https://doi.org/10.1002/cber.19120450116).
2. Y. Saito, K. Nakatsu, M. Shiro, H. Kuroya, "The first-row transition-metal series of tris­­(ethyl­enedi­amine) di­acetate Determination of the absolute configuration of optically active complex ion, $\ce{[Co(en)3]^3+}$, by means of X-rays,"  *Acta Crystallographica* **1955**, *8*, 729-730 (https://doi.org/10.1107/S0365110X55002211).
3. Duyen N. K. Pham, Mrittika Roy, James A. Golen, David R. Manke, "The first-row transition-metal series of tris­­(ethyl­enedi­amine) di­acetate complexes M(en)32 (M is Mn, Fe, Co, Ni, Cu, and Zn),"  *Acta Crystallographica Section C* **2017**, *73(6)*, 442-446 (https://doi.org/10.1107/S2053229617006738).

Comment: this answer misses an important point. The individual ions in the structure *are* chiral but the overall crystal is not.

Comment: @matt_black: The major point of the question is chirality of the complex ion, not the crystal structure. Crystallography is one way to show the absolute stereochemistry. The crystal coordination shows that. Should have read the article.

Comment: Take my comment as a suggestion for ow to make your answer clearer. Had you added a simple sentence explaining the point I made, the answer would be totally fine. But that point is buried in useful but unnecessary detail.

Comment: @matt_black: Finally, I got your point. I was only try to point out that OP's textbook statement is incorrect. I apologize for my ignorance. The answer has been corrected since.